# Saving Google Data Studio Report with Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, looker-studio, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am trying to save a report in Google Data Studio using Katalon Recorder to automate a process. A change is only recorded when a user clicks somewhere on the page. Since Katalon Recorder doesn't actually "click" the change isn't saved. Is there a javascript function I can execute to save the report? I imagine it is similar to other Google Docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Katalon/Seledium DOES actually click on things.

If i understand the question right, you want to click "anywhere" on the page? If so, have you tried [Click Offset](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Click+Offset) ?